# javascript initialise Float64Array of unknown length and add value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got a function that requires a Float64Array and I'm trying to create one programmatically with unknown length and add an unknown number of data points to it.
Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/butvw81a/1/

```
var array = new Float64Array();

array[0]="2";
array[1]= 4555434;
console.log(array[0]); // undefined
```

This console output gives undefined

Do I have to create a normal array with:
var array = [];
and somehow create the float64array with that once the data's been added to it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `new Float32Array().from( arrayLikeOrIterable )` to convert a standard array to Float32. Check the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array for more details on how to use these data structures.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unknown length"?